# Android adding place icon in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers, marker

I got a way to remove all the default places from the map , i would like to add a place icon i.e. a shape that represent what is this place activity .

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(newLocation)
                .visible(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.raw.red)));
```

this code change the shape of the marker to a image , but i want to add the default shape of place which is the small circles representing the place activity and make it clickable  as this [image: the final shape of the map]

Comment: hey how did you get those google places icons . I have plain map but no those Icon. What are you using. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add custom icon from drawables, for example:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(newLocation)
                .visible(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_icon));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :)